# how to customize the wordpress url of a single page as per our wish?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

How to redirect the below url in wordpress using either .htaccess or else using functions.php. I want to change **only this url** when some access the actual url that should change .  Please help for this..

For example:

This is Url: When some one going to access means

```
http://domain.com/products/?id=3&name=cutter
```

The above url need to change like this:

```
http://domain.com/3/cutter
```

Answer (score 1):

If using Woocommerce, The Permalink settings are located under *settings >> permalinks*:

[image]

From here you may change the URL structure as you wish.

You may want to make sure that you do not have any hard-coded links in your pages pointing to the old URLs if you change them.

If changing a **single URL**, you can optionally do this from the page editor:

[image]

Comment: I just want to do a particular page only not entire page.

Comment: You should state this in your question.  I have edited your question to reflect this.

Answer (score -1):

In Wordpress you can change appearance of your URL in Settings -> Direct Links.

If you wish to play some with .htaccess file than you can do it like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^your-addres-users-will-see$ /path/to-your/file.php
```

Be careful, because WP might not find those files in `<a>` tags, when you rewrite their names.

Comment: 1992 I just want to do a particular page only not entire page. Also query string value will change dynamically